# JQuery-DataTables-ColumnFilter filteration issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datacolumn

I am using `JQuery-DataTables-ColumnFilter` plugin.I am having two tables, when i am trying to filter data on first table , it is searching in another table(#example1) instead of (#example[image])

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#example').dataTable()
          .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ {type: "text"},
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "number" },
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'C', 'U', 'X']  }
                ]

        });
         $('#example1').dataTable()
          .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ {type: "text"},
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "number" },
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'C', 'U', 'X']  }
                ]

        });
});
```

Comment: How are you filtering? Where are you typing keywords?

Comment: As I am using dataTable().columnFilter, Filter is applied to table footer with all specified columns

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which shows the problem? It should work like in this [example](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn-history/r72/trunk/multipleTables.html).

Comment: @Raidri I need same functionality what is shown in above example

Comment: Then copy the code from that example. And if that doesn't work, we need to see more from your page to help.

Comment: Most probably the plugin is using some data structure for search. So applying plugin overrides previous

Comment: I just copied the code of the example from http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html and there I duplicated the table (named it example2). It works fine for me...

Answer (score 2):

No problem at all with more than one table.

Make sure IDs tables and IDs in function call are identical.

#### HTML

```
<table id="example" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"  style="width:980px">
    ...
</table>
<table id="example1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"  style="width:980px">
    ...
</table>
```

#### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#example').dataTable()
          .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ {type: "text"},
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "number" },
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'C', 'U', 'X']  }
                ]

        });
         $('#example1').dataTable()
          .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ {type: "text"},
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "text" },
                     { type: "number" },
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     {type: "text"},
                     { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'C', 'U', 'X']  }
                ]

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping your code in a IIFE and see what happens! maybe its a scope conflict!.. something like so

```
$(function(){

    ;(function(){

    $('#example').dataTable().columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [ {type: "text"},
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "number" },
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'C', 'U', 'X']  }
            ]

        });

    }());

    ;(function(){

    $('#example1').dataTable().columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [ {type: "text"},
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "number" },
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 {type: "text"},
                 { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'C', 'U', 'X']  }
            ]

        });
    }());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the version differences. I've made a working example so you can test it out.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pjfza0h/)

Here are versions (from JsFiddle) that worked for me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```